# Matlab Confidence Interval for Degrees of Freedom

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

I would like to calculate a Confidence Interval along with my Degrees of Freedom (DOF) estimation in Matlab. I am trying to run the following line of code:

```
[R, DoF, ciDOF] = copulafit('t', U); % fit the copula
```

The code line without the "ciDOF" arguments takes between 1-3 hours to run with my data. I tried to run the code with the "ciDOF" argument several times, but the calculations seem to take very long (I stopped the calculation after 8 hours). No error message is generated.

Does anyone have experience with this argument and could kindly tell me how long I should expect the calculation to take (the size of my data is 167*19) and if I have specified the "ciDOF" argument correctly?

Many thanks for the help!

Carolin

Answer (score 1):

If your data matrix `U` is of size `167 x 19`, then what you are asking for is a copula-fit distribution dependent on 19-dimensions, making your copula a distribution in a 20-dimensional space with 19 dependent variables.

This is almost definitely why it is taking so long, because whether it is your intention or not, you are asking MATLAB to solve a minimization problem of taking 19 marginal distributions and come-up with the 19-variate joint distribution (the copula) where each marginal distribution (represented by `167 x 1` row-vectors) is uniform.

Most-likely this is a limit of the MATLAB implementation that is iterating through many independent computations and then trying to combine them together to fit the joint distribution's ideal conditions.

First and foremost -- and not to be insulting or insinuating -- you should definitely check that you really are trying to find a 19-variate copula. Also, just in case, make sure that your matrix `U` is oriented in the proper way, because if you have it transposed, you could be trying to ask for the solution to a 167-variate distribution.

But, if this is what you are actually trying to do, there is not really an easy way to predict how long it will take or how long it should take. Even with multiple dimensions, if your marginals are simple or uniform already, that would greatly reduce the copula computation. But, really, there is no way to tell.

Although this may seem like a cop-out, you may actually have better luck switching from MATLAB to R, especially if you have a lot of multivariate data, and you will probably find a lot more functionality in R than MATLAB. R is freely available and comes with a Graphical User Interface (GUI), in-case you aren't comfortable with command-line programming.

There are many more sources, but here is one PDF lecture on computing copula-fits in R:

http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/copulasPowerpoint.pdf

Comment: Hi TommyPKeane, thanks for your very detailed and helpful comment! I really appreciate it! Fitting a 19-variate copula is indeed what I want to estimate. I was now able to calculate the confidence Interval and it took about 5 hours this time. It sounds as if R might indeed be quicker to calculate, however I do not have experience with the coding language and I have therefore decided to stay with Matlab for this project. Thanks for helping out again! Carolin